# Can I use a type of an existing table's column when creating a table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am curious if I could use the type of an existing table's column when I create another column. Just as using a data type like varchar, I would like to have my column the same type as a column in another table.

I am imagining something like
 CREATE TABLE FIRST (id NUMBER(5), name VARCHAR(25))

and then

CREATE TABLE SECOND (id NUMBER(6), value FIRST.NAME%TYPE)

and the type of the VALUE column would be VARCHAR(25)

I see this as a generic SQL question, though I am using Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
  CREATE TABLE SECOND AS (
    SELECT ID, NAME AS VALUE 
    FROM FIRST
    WHERE 1 = 2
  );
```

If think the %type syntax is a plsql thing only

Comment: This would just create the SECOND table as a copy of the FIRST table (of course with no data). What I want is for one column of my choice in the SECOND table to use the type of one column in the FIRST table

Comment: @Tchypp, you could build the table creation script dynamically (retrieving the column definitions from user_tab_columns) and execute it. But I think you're looking for an easier solution, like the one that is available in PLSQL using the %TYPE sntax.

Comment: ok, even if we would reduce to PLSQL, the %TYPE trick does not work. A PLSQL solution would fit for me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL, you'd write a CREATE DOMAIN statement.

```
CREATE DOMAIN my_name_type VARCHAR(25);
```

But I don't think Oracle supports `CREATE DOMAIN`, so you I think you need to create an object instead.

```
create type my_name_type as object
( my_name_col varchar2(25));
```

In either case, you'd use it directly in creating a table.

```
create table test (
    user_name my_name_type
);
```

I recall that the syntax for INSERT statements is a little weird; check the docs for that.

Answer (score -1):

You could do this in SQL Server by using `SELECT INTO`:

```
SELECT TOP 0 CAST(0 as int) as 'id', Field
INTO NewTable
FROM OtherTable
```

Comment: ...which is why I mention in the first line **in SQL Server**.